# How do I add celery logs to task specific file and stdout?

Tags: python, logging, celery

I want to put the celery logs to 2 different places:

- A task specific file (`<task_id>.log`), as `[time][<task.kwargs.id>]: message`
- Stdout, in Json format as `{"@timestamp": "timestamp", "task_id": "celery_task_id", "kwargs": "kwargs sent in celery task", "message": "<message>"}`

I also don't want to disable default celery logger.

I am stuck with it for a long time. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For that you need to implement your own Logger and configure Celery to use it. There is a section in the documentation which explains how.